# Bandpass filter matlab explanation

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to learn about bandpass filter, and I understood the theory, or the basic idea. However, I have been trying to work with the following code, but am able to understand it completely and mold it to the working I want it to.

```
    clc;
    close all;
    clear all;

    n=0:300000;
    delay = 10000;
    wc=.2*pi;
    w0=.4*pi;

    hLP=(wc/pi)*sinc((wc/pi)*(n-delay));
    hBP=2*cos(n*w0).*hLP;
    [Happrox,W]=freqz(hBP,1); 
    plot(W,abs(Happrox));
    xlabel('frequency'); 
    ylabel('magnitude');
    title('Band pass Filter');
```

I got the following filter design when I run this code

[image]

I wanted the X axis to extended till 255 and I was able to achieve that using `xlim`. Now, I am facing problems when it comes to altering the frequency limits of the bandpass. That is why I felt I need to understand the code. Please help me with an explanation.

`wc` and `w0` are the values to be altered for changing the frequency bands, but am not able to get the exact value of the frequency I require, for eg say from 12 to 250. If you can help me with an explanation, I feel I can get it done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The W variable that you got from the freqz function has unites of radians per sample and extends from 0 to pi.  To get the frequency in Hz, you need to provide the sample rate, Fs and also the number of points you want, N.

Replace your call to freqz with these lines:

```
N = 200; % 200 points in frequency vector
Fs = 100; % 100 Hz sample rate
[Happrox,W]=freqz(hBP,1, N, Fs);
```