# Designing a low-pass filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I am new to MATLAB so go easy on me.

I am wondering how I would design a low-pass filter to filter out the high frequency component of a signal. The signal is a sine wave of low frequency combined with a sine wave of high frequency, and the sampling rate is 1000Hz.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you need is a bandpass filter then to separate the two frequencies. Maybe [Bandpass filter matlab explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580096/bandpass-filter-matlab-explanation) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

I misunderstood.  I thought you wanted to filter out a single frequency component.  You said your signal consisted of a sine wave at a low frequency with a sine wave at a high frequency.  As such, I figured a notch filter would be sufficient.

In terms of LPF design, it depends on **what kind of filter** you want.  There are many topologies - Butterworth, Chebyshev, etc.

I would recommend you take a look at MathWorks - in particular, their examples on LPF design.  Look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/designing-low-pass-fir-filters.html

Once you extract the right coefficients for your FIR filter, you can then use `filter` to filter your signal.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I am not sure if a notch filter would be ideal. The range of frequencies I wish to keep is quite low and the high frequency component of the wave has a very high and varying frequency. I may be wrong but it seems that just a simple low-pass filter seems to be enough.

Comment: My bad.  I thought you wanted to filter out a single frequency.  In that case, take a look at this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/designing-low-pass-fir-filters.html

Comment: My problem with a notch filter is that the frequency of the high frequency component varies by +-10KHz, the frequency its self is in the order of MHz. The low frequency signal is around 100Hz. I feel that it would be quite easy with a low-pass filter.

Comment: You said that your signal consisted of a sine wave of low frequency with a sine wave of high frequency.  I interpreted that as two sinusoids superimposed on top of each other, which is why I suggested a notch filter.  If you truly want a LPF, look at the link I have posted.